# Required Validator and compare validators do not work!

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, ajax

I am trying to see the validation part working. I have few required field validators and compare field validators, etc.

```
<div>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCompany" ValidationGroup="groupProfile"
     ControlToValidate="txtCompany" runat="server" 
     ErrorMessage="- Company Name Required" Display="Dynamic" />
</div>
<div>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAddress" ValidationGroup="groupProfile"
     ControlToValidate="txtAddress" runat="server"
     ErrorMessage="- Address 1 Required" Display="Dynamic" />
</div>
```

This is my save button, validation has to happen when this button is clicked.

```
<tr>
  <td align="center">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/green-save.gif" 
        OnClick="btnSave_Click" TabIndex="22" ValidationGroup="groupProfile" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

The popup that comes when the save button is clicked is this..

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" align="left" style="padding-left: 75px; padding-top: 10px;">
    Do you wish to update the Location Information as well.
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center" colspan="4">
    <asp:Button ID="btnYesMerchant" Text ="Yes" runat="server" class="popupButton"
        causesvalidation="true" OnClientClick="$find('mdlpop').hide(); return true;" 
        onclick="btnYessave_Click"/> 
    <asp:Button ID = "btnNoMerchant" Text ="No" runat ="server" class="popupButton" 
        causesvalidation="true" OnClientClick="$find('mdlpop').hide(); return true;" 
        onclick="btnNosave_Click"/>
    <asp:Button Id="btnCancel" Text ="Cancel" runat="server" class="popupButton" />                             
  </td>
</tr>
```

Where am i doing wrong? i am in a serious mess, i guess :(

Comment: What would you like to happen, and what happens exactly?

Comment: there's some code that is bound to the btnSave on client side it seems, since I don't see any popup code in your post

Comment: post html as rendered. also any javascript your are adding server-side.

Comment: Check your javascript it might have some errors

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have included the [asp:ScriptManage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx)r on your page.  In addition to that check for javascript errors and (if any) add them to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have assigned the popup to the button, so the popup is being called when the button is clicked. Now i have changed the flow. For the button, i have written a javascript function that will validate and calls the popup to show if validation is passed. This worked. Thank you all..